# wordpress multisite with sub-domain pretty permalinks

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am trying to set up a wordpress (3.4.2) multisite. The current site already has the following apache rules applied, *which i do not have the permissions to edit*

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xxx:80>
  ServerName foo.example.nl
  ServerAlias www.foo.example.nl
  DocumentRoot /web/sites/example.nl/foo/www
  RewriteEngine On
<Location />
  Allow from all
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

this works fine however i found that trying to set up permalinks with 'Post name' options always gives me a 404 redirect.
http://foo.example.nl/post1 = 404 Not Found

at the moment i have un-installed multisite just to try and get the pretty urls working with the sub-domain but after trying lots of different variations of my .htaccess but nothing seems to be working. here is the current .htaccess wordpress generates:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you are probably limited from using `.htaccess` to configure the `RewriteRules`. If you referent to the Wordpress documentation on [Using "Pretty" Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks) you will see that you need to have `Options FollowSymLinks` enabled as well as `AllowOverride Fileinfo` or `AllowOverride All` to be able to use the pretty URL configuration in `.htaccess`. Since these don't seem to be set your `<VirtualHost>` it is likely your problem, since they are typically *not* set at a higher level in the Apache configuration.